# How do I adjust animation easing in Blender?

Tags: animation, interface

Whenever I animate something I dislike the result because blender automatically gives your animations very stretched out and noticable easing, Is there a way to adjust this easing? Im looking for options such as: Changing easing from easing on both ends to only easing in or only easing out,changing the easing intensity and lenght and the ability to remove it altogether.

Comment: In case easing doesn't ring a bell, its old name is slow in and slow out.

Comment: Im not sure which answer to mark as the right one as both give useful insight.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the Graph Editor for this. The Graph Editor allows you full control over the animation curves, including options to vary the Easing Type (menu Key/Easing Type or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>), setting the Interpolation Mode (menu Key/Interpolation Mode or <kbd>T</kbd>) - which includes additional Easing options, or by manipulating the curve bezier handles.

[image: graph editor]

Answer (score 6):

This will give you some things to experiment with:

File >> User Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).

Click the Editing tab up on the top of the User Preferences Dialog Box.

In the Third Column from the left there are settings for **New F-Curve Defaults**

[image]

Try changing the Interpola setting.