# How to make looping/cyclic clock-hand animation seamless?

Tags: animation, looping

I am making a (non realistic) clock hands animation. But there's a slight pause at the end of the loop. I have copy/pasting the first frame to last, making the graph cyclic, using the steps modifier, but none of them seems to work for me. :(

[image]

<s>Also, how do I create and upload those nice gif captures I often see here in theis forum? Is there a native method to capture gifs from blender and host to here?</s>

**UPDATE:** In the other thread marked as duplicate of this one, the 'set keyframes as linear option' solves this issue, but not completely. There is still a tiny pause at the end of the loop, probably due to the end keyframe sharing the same values as the first. But if I duplicate the first frame to the last, the entire clock animation rewinds at the last frame, and then starts again normally.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/how-do-i-adjust-animation-easing-in-blender

Comment: please see OP update.

Comment: In this case you don't even need a loop. As a matter of fact you only need a single keframe and a generator in the graph editor. Add a single keyframe to the rotation of the clock handle. Once you have a keyframe in the grph editor open the properties panel (Press the N key), go to the Modifiers Tab and add a modifier>Generator. Play with the second polynomial to generate a line that defines the movement of the clock hand in the direction you need. The angle of the line will determine the speed of the rotation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhMnU.gif

Comment: If you must do it with keyframes (so that the rotation values stay form 0 to 360) then add your keyframes for rotation at 0 and -360, set the interpolation to linear and in the modifiers create a cycle. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndG1q.gif

Comment: Thanks! Both your solutions work perfectly. But I will go with the second one as it keeps the rotation values within proper range.